# Move elements from one arraylist to another arraylist asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have two arraylist

```
public ArrayList myA = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList myB = new ArrayList();
```

When comes a new value in `myA`, delete the old content of `myB`, moving the old content from `myA` to `myB` and in `myA` have the new value

For example:

```
myA("value1","value2","value3");
myB("","","");
```

Come the new values:

```
myA("value4","value5","value6");
myB("value1","value2","value3");
```

Come another values:

```
myA("value7","value8","value9");
myB("value4","value5","value6");
```

Please help me

Comment: What version of .net are you running? Have you considered using a `List<T>` if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this should do the work

```
// Initial values
        ArrayList myA = new ArrayList() { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
        ArrayList myB = new ArrayList() { "", "", "" };

        // New values
        ArrayList myC = new ArrayList() { "value4", "value5", "value6" };

        // Clear the old values from myB and add the old values of myA to myB
        myB.Clear();
        myB.AddRange(myA);

        // Clear the old values from mya and add the new values to myA
        myA.Clear();
        myA.AddRange(myC);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ArrayWithBackup : List<String>
{
    List<String> arrayWithBackup;
    List<String> backupArray;
    public ArrayWithBackup()
    {
        arrayWithBackup = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddStrings(List<String> inputs)
    {
        if (backupArray != null && backupArray.Count > 0)
            backupArray.Clear();

        backupArray = new List<string>(arrayWithBackup);
        arrayWithBackup.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count; ++i)
        {
            arrayWithBackup.Add(inputs[i]);
        }
    }

    public void PrintArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array contains:");
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayWithBackup.Count; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine("Index {0}: {1}", i, arrayWithBackup[i]);
    }

    public void PrintBackupArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BackupArray contains:");
        for (int i = 0; i < backupArray.Count; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine("Index {0}: {1}", i, backupArray[i]);
    }

    public List<String> GetArray()
    {
        return arrayWithBackup;
    }

    public List<String> GetBackupArray()
    {
        return backupArray;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayWithBackup awb = new ArrayWithBackup();

        List<String> inputs = new List<String>();
        inputs.Add("one");
        inputs.Add("two");
        inputs.Add("three");

        awb.AddStrings(inputs);
        inputs.Clear();

        inputs.Add("four");
        inputs.Add("five");
        inputs.Add("six");
        awb.AddStrings(inputs);

        awb.PrintArray();
        awb.PrintBackupArray();
    }
}

//Output:
//Array contains:
//Index 0: four
//Index 1: five
//Index 2: six

//BackupArray contains:
//Index 0: one
//Index 1: two
//Index 2: three
```